# Errors after upgrading android billing version to 6

Tags: android, in-app-billing

Please help me to update code to new version of android billing.i quit this project but some users keep asking why its not available and woking. realised few updates are needed.upgrading to vrsion 6 from 3. working on this project after 2 years. This app has in app purchases. i am required to upgrade this library in order to upload new release.

package com.navlab.recical.Billing;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;

import com.android.billingclient.api.AcknowledgePurchaseParams;
import com.android.billingclient.api.AcknowledgePurchaseResponseListener;
import com.android.billingclient.api.BillingClient;
import com.android.billingclient.api.BillingClientStateListener;
import com.android.billingclient.api.BillingFlowParams;
import com.android.billingclient.api.BillingResult;
import com.android.billingclient.api.Purchase;
import com.android.billingclient.api.PurchasesUpdatedListener;
import com.android.billingclient.api.SkuDetails;
import com.android.billingclient.api.SkuDetailsParams;
import com.android.billingclient.api.SkuDetailsResponseListener;
import com.navlab.recical.MyLab.Tinku;
import com.navlab.recical.R;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static com.android.billingclient.api.BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP;

public class Billu implements PurchasesUpdatedListener {


    private BillingClient billingClient;
    List<String>skuList=new ArrayList<>();
    String sku;
    Context context;
    Dialog dialog;
    Button buttonBuyProduct;
    TextView tv_purchasedAlready;
    Activity activity;
    Tinku tinku=new Tinku();
    Actions action;

    public Billu(){}

    public Billu(Context context, String sku,Dialog dialog,Activity activity,Actions action ){
        this.context=context;
        this.sku=sku;
        this.dialog=dialog;
        this.activity=activity;
        this.action=action;

        buttonBuyProduct=dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnUpgrade);
        buttonBuyProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                purchase();
            }
        });
        tv_purchasedAlready=dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv_alreadyPurchased);

        dialog.show();
        skuList.add(sku);

        billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(context)
                .enablePendingPurchases().setListener(this).build();
    }

    //initiate purchase on button click
    public void purchase() {
        //check if service is already connected
        if (billingClient.isReady()) {
            initiatePurchase();
        }
        //else reconnect service
        else{
            billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(context).enablePendingPurchases().setListener(this).build();
            billingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onBillingSetupFinished(BillingResult billingResult) {
                    if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                        initiatePurchase();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(context,"Error "+billingResult.getDebugMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void initiatePurchase() {
        SkuDetailsParams params= SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder()
                .setSkusList(skuList)
                .setType(INAPP)
                .build();

        billingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(params,
                new SkuDetailsResponseListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSkuDetailsResponse(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult, List<SkuDetails> skuDetailsList) {
                        if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK)
                        {
                            if (skuDetailsList != null && skuDetailsList.size() > 0)
                            {
                                BillingFlowParams flowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                                        .setSkuDetails(skuDetailsList.get(0))
                                        .build();
                                billingClient.launchBillingFlow(activity, flowParams);
                            }
                            else{
                                //try to add item/product id "purchase" inside managed product in google play console
                                Toast.makeText(context,"Purchase Item not Found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(context,
                                    " Error "+billingResult.getDebugMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public void onPurchasesUpdated(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult, @Nullable List<Purchase> purchases) {
        //if item newly purchased
        if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && purchases != null)
        {
            handlePurchases(purchases);
        }

        //if item already purchased then check and reflect changes
        else if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED)
        {
            Purchase.PurchasesResult queryAlreadyPurchasesResult = billingClient.queryPurchases(INAPP);
            List<Purchase> alreadyPurchases = queryAlreadyPurchasesResult.getPurchasesList();
            if(alreadyPurchases!=null)
            {
                handlePurchases(alreadyPurchases);
            }
        }

        //if purchase cancelled
        else if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.USER_CANCELED)
        {
            Toast.makeText(context,"Purchase Canceled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        // Handle any other error msgs
        else {
            Toast.makeText(context,"Error "+billingResult.getDebugMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private void handlePurchases(List<Purchase> purchases) {
        for(Purchase purchase:purchases) {
            //if item is purchased
            if (purchase.getSku().equals(purchase.getSku()) && purchase.getPurchaseState() == Purchase.PurchaseState.PURCHASED)
            {
                if (!verifyValidSignature(purchase.getOriginalJson(), purchase.getSignature())) {
                    // Invalid purchase
                    // show error to user
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Error : Invalid Purchase", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                // else purchase is valid
                //if item is purchased and not acknowledged
                if (!purchase.isAcknowledged()) {
                    AcknowledgePurchaseParams acknowledgePurchaseParams =
                            AcknowledgePurchaseParams.newBuilder()
                                    .setPurchaseToken(purchase.getPurchaseToken())
                                    .build();
                    billingClient.acknowledgePurchase(acknowledgePurchaseParams, ackPurchase);
                }
                //else item is purchased and also acknowledged
                else {
                    // Grant entitlement to the user on item purchase
                    if(!tinku.getBoolFromPref(context,context.getResources().getString(R.string.premium_purchased)))
                    {

                        tinku.setBoolInPref(context,context.getResources().getString(R.string.premium_purchased),true);
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Item Purchased", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        //Navigation.findNavController(root).navigate(R.id.action_nav_home_to_fragNewRecipe);
                        action.actionNavigate();
                    }
                }
            }
            //if purchase is pending
            else if( purchase.getSku().equals(purchase.getSku()) && purchase.getPurchaseState() == Purchase.PurchaseState.PENDING)
            {
                Toast.makeText(context,
                        "Purchase is Pending. Please complete Transaction", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            //if purchase is unknown
            else if(purchase.getSku().equals(purchase.getSku()) && purchase.getPurchaseState() == Purchase.PurchaseState.UNSPECIFIED_STATE)
            {
                tinku.setBoolInPref(context,context.getResources().getString(R.string.premium_purchased),false);

//                purchaseStatus.setText("Purchase Status : Not Purchased");
//                purchaseButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Toast.makeText(context, "Purchase Status Unknown", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    AcknowledgePurchaseResponseListener ackPurchase = new AcknowledgePurchaseResponseListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAcknowledgePurchaseResponse(BillingResult billingResult) {
            if(billingResult.getResponseCode()==BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK){
                //if purchase is acknowledged
                // Grant entitlement to the user. and restart activity

                tinku.setBoolInPref(context,context.getResources().getString(R.string.premium_purchased),true);
                dialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(context, "Item Purchased", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                action.actionNavigate();
             }
        }
    };
```